# Extend prefix URIs in SPARQL query

Tags: sparql

I have created a prefix which has various sublevels for example:

```
PREFIX myprefix: <https://myprefix.org/>
```

I have several sublevels of prefix that I have used to organise my data. For example:

```
https://myprefix.org/people 
https://myprefix.org/buildings
https://myprefix.org/plants
```

I would now like to be able to specify the prefix with the extension in a SPARQL query. For example, I would like to select all of the properties in my database connected to the instance with the URI `https://myprefix.org/people/michael` :

```
PREFIX myprefix: <https://myprefix.org/>
select * where { 
    myprefix:people/michael ?p ?o.
} limit 100
```

I have tried several approaches and have been unable to extend the prefix URI in the SPARQL query. I am now wondering if it good practice to use subcategories for prefixes or whether each prefix be complete to the instance or property it is describing.

Is there any advice on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

What I tend to do is to have a prefix for entities and one for ontologies, such as this:
`PREFIX : <http://example.com/entities#>`
`PREFIX ont: <http://example.com/ontology#>`

Then, when I want different entities, I will simply write:
`:people_michael` or `:plants_1234`.

Alternatively, your approach can also work, but in SPARQL you'll need to escape the `/`, so your query will be:

```
    PREFIX myprefix: <https://myprefix.org/>
    
    SELECT *
    WHERE { 
        myprefix:people\/michael ?p ?o.
    }
    LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Thanks, that is useful, I hope to create a URL that points to the resource, would using the / or _  be considered better practice to separate the subcategories in the URL or is just down to personal preference?